# How to open Complete Action Using Activity Box

Tags: android

I tried to find some information about Android window with application selection, but I could not find anything. I was looking for dialog box, where we can click "Open it just once" or "Always use it".

[image: link to the image]

How can I call it? I have to code it by myself or it is build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called as sending user to another application in android. you need to code when and which application it should print when a user click on a specific thing link phone number or Ip address.

> send the user to another app based on an "action" it would like to perform. For example, if your app has the address of a business that you'd like to show on a map, you don't have to build an activity in your app that shows a map. Instead, you can create a request to view the address using an Intent. The Android system then starts an app that's able to show the address on a map. From Android official site.

You can code it for taking the action automatically too.

For opening a web page you can code like this.

```
Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
```

Once you create your intent start it

```
startActivity(intent);
```

It will open that box for you.[Box you wanted](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#StartActivity)

For Complete Description for how to do that go through these android official documentation.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html